# GraphQL query and check the returned data

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I would like to have a query containing a check, for example when querying users, only users that have a non-null email are wanted. How could I add such check? Thanks!

```
users {
  id,
  username,
  email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL fields can have arguments.
So you could pass an argument to your `users` field, named `onlyNonNullEmail: boolean`:

```
type Query {
  users(onlyNonNullEmail: Boolean) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, inside your resolve function:

```
users: (_, args, context, ast) => {
  const { onlyNonNullEmail } = args;

  // If onlyNonNullEmail is true, return only users with a non-null email
  // Else proceed as usual
}
```

Comment: Hi! I added such check and return only if the email is not null. However, I still get null when it does not return the resolved object. I think that in graphQL, it always returns null if there is no valid obj.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code? If `users` is a list of users, you should always be returning an array, even empty

Comment: yep, I figured out that graphQL will always return a null regardless whether the object is null or does not exist. Thanks!