# GraphQL in Gatsbyjs - Only Return Data Which Contains a Particular Field

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I am using GraphQL within the GatsbyJs framework.

I have multiple files with JSON data. The structure of data is similar to this:

```
{
 ...,
 "sections" / "menuSections"
}
```

That last field can be either 'sections' or 'menuSections' in each file. My current graphQL query looks like this:

```
{
  allDataJson {
    nodes {
      menuSections
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns the correct 'menuSections', however, data-files which do not have 'menuSections' are returned as `null`. How can I get GraphQL to only return data from files which contain 'menuSections', i.e. how to return data within which 'menuSections' exist. I am looking for an operator like `$exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `sections` & menuSections are string or arrays of string, maybe you can filter for `null`:

```
{
  "menuSections": "..."
}
```

```
// query
{
  allDataJson(filter: {
    menuSections: {
      ne: null
    }
  }) {
    nodes {
      menuSections
    }
  }
}
```

If they are object, you can still filter for `null`, but it has to be applied to one of the field inside that object. If your objects don't have a common field, this won't work:

```
{
  "menuSections": {
    "menuSectionField": "..."
  }
}
```

```
// query
{
  allDataJson(filter: {
    menuSections: {
      menuSectionField: {
        ne: null
      }
    }
  }) {
    nodes {
      menuSections
    }
  }
}
```

If they are array of objects, you can do the same thing but with `elemMatch`:

```
{
  "menuSections": [
    { "menuSectionField": "..." },
    { "other": "..." }
  ]
}
```

```
// query
allDataJson(filter: {
    menuSections: {
      elemMatch: {
        menuSectionField: {
          ne: null
        }
      }
    }
  }) { ... }
```

Worst case worst, I think you might be able to define some sort of custom types that ensure existence of menuSections so you can query `allDataWithMenuSections` etc., but if filter works it's much simpler.

Comment: A wonderful & comprehensive answer. Thank you for catering to various scenarios. This resolved my issue.

Comment: a graphql newbie here - So is `filter` an operation argument which graphQL inherently supports ?! From what I understand, on the backend WE need to actually write the resolvers to understand the `filter` args and filter the data accordingly. I seem to be missing a piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: @AnandUndavia you are correct, these filter functions are implemented by Gatsbyjs, they are not a part of graphql spec. I guess we should change the question title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there isn't an `$exists` operator in [GraphQL](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Language.Directives). Instead what you can do is add some logic in the resolver to check if a field is not null. I found two older questions related to yours:
[GraphQL query and check the returned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590315/graphql-query-and-check-the-returned-data) 
[GraphQL query: only include field if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451910/graphql-query-only-include-field-if-not-null)